# Why can you cast Maps of different types?

Tags: java, casting, dictionary

I came across an oddity today that I don't quite understand. Take this code, for example:

```
Object iMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>() {{
    put(5, "thing1");
    put(6, "thing2");
}};
Map<String, Object> sMap = (Map<String, Object>)iMap;

// No error, prints out java.lang.Integer:
System.out.println(new ArrayList(sMap.keySet()).get(0).getClass().getName();

// No error, prints out 5:
Object key = new ArrayList<String>(sMap.keySet()).get(0);
System.out.println(key.toString());

// ClassCastException:
String s = new ArrayList<String>(sMap.keySet()).get(0);
```

So, what gives? Why can I cast a Map with keys of type Integer to one of type String without any issues? Shouldn't that throw an error? And why can I even cast to `ArrayList<String>` and *still* get no errors? It's supposedly a list of only Strings, but I can retrieve an Integer from it.

I'm a bit baffled by this, and I'm wondering if anyone here knows enough about the inner workings of these classes to help me out.

Comment: The first four lines of your code won't compile. iMap needs to be declared in the least as a Map.

Comment: @Hovercraft Not true. Try this code for yourself. It compiles.

Comment: @JakeKing: I did test this before I entered the comment. But it doesn't matter as this is a basic Java error and again it should not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast `Map<Integer, Object>` to `Map<String, Object>` "without any issues"... until you try to *use* it.

The problem starts in this line:

```
Map<String, Object> sMap = (Map<String, Object>)iMap;
```

where the compiler warns you with this message:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Map

You ignored that warning.

This is all happening because of [runtime type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) - at runtime there are no types, eg you have just `Map`, etc. Types are just there at compile to help you *not* do what you are doing here.

The reason this line explodes:

```
String s = new ArrayList<String>(sMap.keySet()).get(0);
```

is that the sMap actually refers to the Map that had Integers for keys in its entries. When you actually went to pull one of the keys out, it was an Integer which java then tries to assign to a String... boom!

btw, this part doesn't compile:

```
Object iMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
iMap.put(5, "thing1");
iMap.put(6, "thing2");
```

you would need to cast iMap to `Map<Integer, Object>` like this:

```
Object iMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
((Map<Integer, Object>)iMap).put(5, "thing1");
((Map<Integer, Object>)iMap).put(6, "thing2");
```

Comment: Ah, of course! I always seems to forget about that when using generics. I'll accept this as soon as I can. (StackOverflow is amazing.)

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the "didn't compile" part. When I rigged up a small test of this, I used the lazy "double brace initialization" method.

Answer (score 0):

The first four lines of your code won't compile as iMap must be declared at least as a Map in order to call methods such as get(...) on it.  But your other problem illustrates why it is important to use generics when declaring variables.  So if you declared iMap thusly:

```
  Map<Integer, Object> iMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
```

The compiler would complain rightly when you try to cast it here:

```
Map<String, Object> sMap = (Map<String, Object>)iMap;
```

Comment: No, it won't. As I commented on the question, I've tested this. It compiles and runs.

Comment: Not with any Java compiler I'm familiar with.

Comment: I take it back. My code was slightly different, I'll update my first post. Sorry.